# How to get Solana network status via API?

Tags: api, network-health

Are there any RPC endpoints or public APIs that provide the cluster health information that is available here: https://status.solana.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Actually https://status.solana.com calls an API in the background. See the docs here: https://status.solana.com/api/v2

Answer (score 1):

You can get the health of a specific with https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gethealth.

There isn't any API available for https://status.solana.com/ as of now. You'll need to scrape the data.